# How to make outer border of table to be of a colour different from inner in HTML without using CSS?

Tags: html

Table][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df7xZ.jpg)

I have to make this table in HTML. I don't understand how to make the outer border red while the others stay black. I can't use CSS and when I tried to use bordercolor="red" it changes the whole table border in red. I only want the outer border to be red. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow ! Please read [ask], and [edit] your question to add a [mre] !

Comment: What happens if you write: `<table style="outline: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)">...</table>`.

Comment: @Rounin my teacher told me we can't use CSS only HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `style=""` attribute to your `<table>`.

In the `style=""` attribute, you can add:

```
outline: 1px solid rgb(255, 0, 0)
```

---

**Working Example:**

```html
<table border="1" style="outline: 3px solid rgb(255, 0, 0); width: 90px; height: 90px;">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

**Second Approach (with no CSS at all):**

```html
<table bgcolor="#FF0000" width="90" height="90">
<tr><td>

<table border="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="88" height="88">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
</table>

</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But isn't outline CSS?

Comment: @Tijana - Sure. I thought "no CSS" meant no referenced CSS file. If your constraints are "no CSS at all" then the approach above won't solve your scenario.

Comment: So is it even possible to achieve this without CSS

Comment: @Tijana - I'm sure there are ways to achieve this without CSS. I have add one approach above - it's basically one `<table>` element nested inside another.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table border="1" style="outline: 3px solid red">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
</table>
```